# How to see all TODO comments under a python package in vim?

Tags: python, vim, ide, editor

I'm using python-mode vim plugin for IDE-like development environment and it automatically highlights the word TODO in comments of my source code.

For example,

```
# TODO: refactor something!
```

or,

```
"""
TODO: work on something!
"""
```

and python-mode highlights those words 'TODO'.

I wonder if there's any way to list all of these TODO comments of a python package in a new vertical window like vim's NERDTree plugin so that I can see package-level TODOs and work on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use vimgrep command:

```
:vimgrep /\<TODO\>/j **/*.py
:cope
```

you can map it to a hotkey

```
:nmap ,t :vimgrep /\<TODO\>/j **/*.py | :cope
```

or create new command

```
:com FindTODO :vimgrep /\<TODO\>/j **/*.py | :cope
```

Answer (score 0):

The already mentioned [TaskList plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2607) searches only the current file, and uses a scratch buffer for display. My own [GrepTasks plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4196) basically implements the solution in @hhbcarl's answer, using `:vimgrep` and the quickfix list. You can search the current file via `:GrepHereTasks`, all files in a directory via `:VimGrepTasks`, and several more scopes.

Answer (score -1):

There is a [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2607) just for that.